# How can I upgrade Ubuntu from 9.10 to 10.04 on a netbook with a 4GB root partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, aptitude

I have an Asus EeePC 901, running Ubuntu 9.10. I'd like to upgrade it to 10.04. I don't want to reinstall, since I have a bunch of scripts and programs all set up.

However, when I attempt to upgrade using `sudo do-release-upgrade`, I get an error asking me to free up another ~600MB on `/`.

My `/` is mounted on `sda0`, which is a 4GB SSD. I do not have 600MB worth of deletable stuff on `/`.

I've emptied my trash, and done `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get clean`.

I do have plenty of space in `/home`, mounted on `sda1` (a 16GB SSD).

Is there some way I can tell apt-get to use a different download/temp directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that `do-release-upgrade` was serious about needing the space on the root drive.

It also checks for free space in a bunch of other folders, but it actually needed the extra 600MB to be on `/`. I guess that was the amount of space the new versions of all my packages would take up.

I managed to clear enough space by removing all my old linux kernels (they don't automatically get removed!), and it's downloading the upgrade now.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out where the temporary directory is, and mount something else (an SD card?) to that directory.

Comment: Any idea where it is? I tried looking at the source of `do-release-upgrade` (it's a python script) but it just downloads something else and runs it.

Comment: I'm going to guess that /tmp would be a likely spot.

Answer (score 0):

i have always used 
sudo apt-get upgrade